# when I search through search controller, indexPath doesn't change with original array

Tags: swift, uitableview, search

I did implement search page in my app. I put PFObjects in postsArray, when user searching something, searched object goes in filteredArray. that is what I tried to do.

tableView shows result, but when I tap on it, it show postArray indexPath which is indexPath before I search it. For example, original(postsArray) first item is red, and I searched yello, when I tap yellow tableView Cell, it shows red post.

here is my code for this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

self.myTable.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
self.myTable.reloadData()

self.bringAllDatafromParse()

}


  func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

  self.filterdArray.removeAllObjects()

   let normalizedSearchText = 

searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString

 for posts in self.postsArray {
    var title = ""
    var tag = ""
    if let titleText = posts["titleText"] as? String {
        title = titleText
    }
    if let tagText = posts["tagText"] as? String {
        tag = tagText
    }
    let results = "\(title) \(tag)"

    if results.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(normalizedSearchText) != nil {
        self.filterdArray.addObject(posts)
    }

}

self.myTable.reloadData()

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
if self.resultSearchController.active{
    return self.filterdArray.count
}else
{
    return self.postsArray.count
}

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchTVCE
//cell.textLabel!.text = searchResults[indexPath.row]



var postObjects : PFObject!


if self.resultSearchController.active{
     postObjects = self.filterdArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
}else {

      postObjects = self.postsArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject


}
//솔드
cell.soldLabel.hidden = true

if (postObjects.objectForKey("sold") as! Bool) == true {
    cell.soldLabel.hidden = false

}


// 제목
cell.titleLabel.text = (postObjects.objectForKey("titleText") as! String)

+ " : " + (postObjects.objectForKey("tagText") as! String)


 return cell

}
```

My question is how can I get right indexPath after I get result from search bar.

And after I search and tap on it, it goes another view. but the searchbar doesn't disappear unless I tap on cancel bar button. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good.

However, you are not showing your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function which might give clue for your problem.

My guess is - you are getting index path correct as you are always linking `self.filterdArray` on tableview. As I understand, everything on UI looks good but only when you tap on first cell, new view controller is loaded with the data that belongs to first cell of non-filtered array. I would advise you to put a check on your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and see if data is being fetched correctly. It should look something like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        myData = (self.filterdArray[indexPath.row])!
    } else {
        myData = (self.postsArray[indexPath.row])!
    }

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MySegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "MySegue") {
        let myViewController = segue.destinationViewController as MyViewController
        myViewController.data = self.myData
    }
}
```

And to your other question:

> searchbar doesn't disappear unless I tap on cancel bar button. How do
>   I fix this?

**Just call : `searchController.active = false`**

Comment: yes, you are right, captain. I didn't even put didselectRowAtIndexPath method.  I gotta use that indexPath for activating segue, I am a bit confused, where I can use myData(example above) to get right segue? Do I put in the cellForRowAtIndexPath part?

Comment: That should be pretty simple. Save the data `myData` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, perform the segue and finally implement `prepareForSegue` to fetch the destination VC and pass `myData` to it.

Comment: Could you help me last one?   I did                              var myData = PFObject!()           and the didSelectRowAtIndexPath as you told me ,  destViewController.object = myData as! PFObject     I got an  error     > fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: You should declare it as  `myData = PFObject()`. `!` is a force unwrapping operator and it does not make sense in your statement above.